# Python: execfile from other file's working directory?

Tags: python, working-directory, execfile

I have some code that loads a default configuration file and then allows users to supply their own Python files as additional supplemental configuration or overrides of the defaults:

```
# foo.py

def load(cfg_path=None):
    # load default configuration
    exec(default_config)

    # load user-specific configuration
    if cfg_path:
        execfile(cfg_path)
```

There is a problem, though: `execfile()` executes directives in the file specified by `cfg_path` as if it were in the working directory of `foo.py`, not its own working directory. Thus, `import` directives might fail if the `cfg_path` file does, say, `from m import x` where `m` is a module in the same directory as `cfg_path`.

How do I `execfile()` from the working directory of its argument, or otherwise achieve an equivalent result? Also, I've been told that `execfile` is deprecated in Python 3 and that I should be using `exec`, so if there's a better way that I should be doing this, I'm all ears.

**Note:** I don't think solutions which merely change the working directory are correct. That won't put those modules on the interpreter's module-lookup path, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[os.chdir](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=os#os.chdir) lets you change the working directory as you wish (you can extract the working directory of `cfg_path` with `os.path.dirname`); be sure to first get the current directory with [os.getcwd](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=os#os.getcwd) if you want to restore it when you're done exec'ing `cfg_path`.

Python 3 does indeed remove `execfile` (in favor of a sequence where you read the file, `compile` the contents, then `exec` them), but you need not worry about that, if you're currently coding in Python 2.6, since the [2to3](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/2to3.html?highlight=execfile) source to source translation deals with all this smoothly and seamlessly.

**Edit**: the OP says, in a comment, that `execfile` launches a separate process and does not respect the current working directory.  This is false, and here's an example showing that it is:

```
import os

def makeascript(where):
  f = open(where, 'w')
  f.write('import os\nprint "Dir in file:", os.getcwd()\n')
  f.close()

def main():
  where = '/tmp/bah.py'
  makeascript(where)
  execfile(where)
  os.chdir('/tmp')
  execfile(where)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Running this on my machine produces output such as:

```
Dir in file: /Users/aleax/stko
Dir in file: /private/tmp
```

clearly showing that `execfile` **does** keep using the working directory that's set at the time `execfile` executes.  (If the file executed changes the working directory, that will be reflected after `execfile` returns -- exactly because everything **is** taking place in the same process!).

So, whatever problems the OP is still observing are *not* tied to the current working directory (it's hard to diagnose what they may actually be, without seeing the code and the exact details of the observed problems;-).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work for me. `execfile()` appears to be launching an entirely new process with its own working directory, which isn't the same as the one I'm launching from.

Comment: No, @Kyle, `execfile` does not launch a separate process, and it **does** respect the current working directory. Editing my answer to show a simple example proving that you're wrong.